# Создать bat файл для перекидывания определенных логов в текстовой документ

Tags: bat

может мой вопрос покажеться примитивным, но не могу понять как можно отправить логи из командной строки после выполнения команды, в текстовый документ. Необходимо отправить только определенные команды. Я сделал так:

```
D:\Soft\file.bat > D:\Soft\1.txt
```

Но он выводит только одну строчку, а у меня в логах их много.
И как можно сделать так чтобы перекидывались те логи в которых, допустим, есть слово «Ошибка». Заранее спасибо.

Comment: т.е. file.bat выводит в консоль много много строк с логами?

Comment: Да, 50+ и из них нужно находить ошибочные

Comment: Используйте findstr и выводите только строки с ошибкой. Вообще можно задать параметр bat файла и выводить Error, Warning и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.